# Play Audio Through 3 Different Bluetooth Speakers

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I want to play a story divided into three mp3 files through three different speakers.

For example: begin playing file 1 through speaker 1. Once it's over, play file 2 through speaker 2. When it ends, play file 3 through speaker 3.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly is your problem with that?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it ... I would like to turn on the raspberry and start the file 1

Comment: How are you going to connect 3 speakers to the RPi? RPi's do have audio out, but its only 2 channel (stereo). Are you going to use 3 USB sounds cards? Also show us what you've tried, what are you using? Why did you tag "bluetooth", but dont mention anything about it?

Comment: I have only one sound card. My question it’s exactly that it’s possible connecting 3 speaker Bluetooth, for my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3, can't connect to more than one bluetooth speaker via pulseaudio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46868/raspberry-pi-3-cant-connect-to-more-than-one-bluetooth-speaker-via-pulseaudio), at least for the non-trivial part. Once you have multiple audio sinks, any decent player should provide an option to select the one you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a two-year old [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46868/raspberry-pi-3-cant-connect-to-more-than-one-bluetooth-speaker-via-pulseaudio) similar to this. The problem that you're trying to solve here is to connect to multiple Bluetooth speakers. That post, and [others](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/19621/connect-multiple-bluetooth-speakers-with-raspberry-pi) show that you will need to use a Bluetooth dongle that supports connecting to multiple devices.

Depending on the operating system that you're using, you're going to need to follow certain steps to be able to play sound through more than one speaker. Here's [an example using Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices).